# TensorFlow KeyError Input_1

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to make retraining Tensorflow MobileNetV2 but I am getting a Keyerror Input_1 when I run below code

```
for test_image, test_label in train_dataset.take(1):break

print(base_model(test_image).shape)
```

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Kka.png)

Any Solution much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please copy & paste the error message rather then making screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

In the input tensor, add `name` attribute and set it to Input_1.

Comment: `input_layer =  tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=image_shape, batch_size=None, name = "image")` You mean this one ? please helpme @Abhishek Verma